# NameError: name 'Atk' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

Okay, so I still don't know whats going on (I'm getting a weird error, I had to edit the post and remove stuff) here's my code, any ideas why its not working? I've tried a lot of stuff, I'm not sure whats wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/PycharmProjects/Arcade Game/AttackDirectory.py", line 111, in <module>
     Battle()
File "C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/PycharmProjects/Arcade Game/AttackDirectory.py", line 106, in Battle
command()
File "C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/PycharmProjects/Arcade Game/AttackDirectory.py", line 92, in command
cmd = input('What Will You Do?')
File "string", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Atk' is not defined




    ThiefPdmg = (lambda x: (round(x*0.75)))(Thief['stats']['Attack'])

    ThiefMdmg = (lambda x: (round(x*0.75)))(Thief['stats']['Magic'])

    ThiefHP = Thief['stats']['HP']

    ImpDMG = (lambda x: (round(x*0.75 / Thief['lvl'] + 1)))(Imp['stats']['Attack'])

    ImpHP = Imp['stats']['HP']

    def Attack(Attacker, Defender):

AttackerDMG = ThiefPdmg
Defenderhp = Imp['stats']['HP']

print('You Attacked!')

    if Thief['stats']['Speed'] >= Imp['stats']['Speed']:
            ImpHP - ThiefPdmg

    if Imp['stats']['Speed'] > Thief['stats']['Speed'] :
            ThiefHP - ImpDMG

    if ImpHP <= 0:
            print('{} Was Killed!'.format(Imp['name']))


    def command():

cmd = input('What Will You Do?')

if 'Atk' in cmd:
    Attack()

else:
    Pass

    def Battle():

    Attackerhp = Thief['stats']['HP']
    Defenderhp = Imp['stats']['HP']

print('An imp appeared!')
print('                ')
while Defenderhp and Attackerhp > 0:
    command()

if Defenderhp <= Defenderhp:
    print('Took {} Damage!'.format(Enemy['name'], Dmg or Mdmg))

    Battle()
```

Comment: Is the indentation in your post the same as the indentation in your source code?

Comment: No, I copied and pasted it in right but stack overflow makes you put extra indentations so it messed it up

Comment: You can [edit] your post, copy-paste the source code, then select it and press Ctrl+K to format it automatically

Comment: oh thanks, I didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is named `command`, and you're trying to read input into a variable called `command`. Python is apparently confusing the two, and trying to search for 'Attack' within the `command` function, which is an error.

I'd suggest you rename your input variable something like `cmd` and see if the problem goes away.

```
def get_command():
    action = input('What will you do? ').lower()
    if action == 'attack':
        Attack()
    else: 
        print("Wimp!")
```

Comment: I just shut my laptop down for the night, so I'll get back to you tomorrow and see if it worked

Comment: Now you're trying to pass `Attack` as the prompt string. That's a function name. Try changing that to: `cmd = input('What will you do? ')`

Comment: Okay, let me try changing that and I'll see if it works

Comment: It didn't fix all the errors, I'll update the code and the error

Comment: Oops! My bad. You're using python 2, not 3. You need to replace `input(` with `raw_input(`. Sorry.

Comment: It's fine, I confuse people a lot because most people use 3